# Import wallet programatically

Tags: wallet, private-key-import, wallet-import

I am using the https://www.blockchain.com/ wallet API: https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3

I am not very deep into crypto, but is there a way to allow the user to import his existing wallet into my app and add it as an HD wallet into my main wallet ?
I do not see any API endpoint for that, also I cannot find an apporipriate support email for contact with technical support on https://www.blockchain.com/

Whatever I searched for it showed apps for importing my wallet into existing apps, but I want to make this functionality available in my app.

Answer (score 1):

> **is there a way to allow the user to import his existing wallet into my app**

That looks a bit like this API function:

https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api says

> Create Wallet API
>
> ---
>
> **Create blockchain wallets programmatically**
>
> The create_wallet method can be used to create a new blockchain.info bitcoin wallet.
>
> URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create
> Method: POST or GET
>
> - $password The password for the new wallet. Must be at least 10
>   characters in length.
> - $api_code An API code with create wallets permission.
> - **$priv A private key to add to the wallet** (Wallet import
>   format preferred). (Optional)
> - $label A label to set for the first> address in the wallet. Alphanumeric only. (Optional)
> - $email An email to associate with the new wallet i.e. the email address of the user
>   you are creating this wallet on behalf of. (Optional)
>
> Please create an API code here including permissions to "Create Wallets".

Your app can read an existing wallet file, extract the private key (or keys) and use this function to create blockchain wallets containing those keys (and hence allowing the spending of all money "in" that existing wallet file)

Maybe there is some feature of this that you find unsuitable - but haven't explained fully why?

It is not unusual for businesses to require a different arrangement with merchants using their services commercially as a back-end. Whether your use might fit into this category is unclear, but a read of the [Terms & Conditions](https://www.blockchain.com/legal/api-terms) for commercial use of their service might clarify this.

Comment: Looks like I've overlooked this.
It looks like exactly the thing that I need.
I just an example wallet.dat to try it out, and here comes my next question.
I have a wallet in blockchain.com, how can I get my wallet.dat file to test this out ?